# insert day of the week based on YYYY/MM/DD format

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the day of the week to be represented based on an existing date in a column. For Example 2019/03/26 would be shown in one column and in the adjoining column the word/date Tuesday would be present/instantiated

```
Sub InputDate()

Dim StartDate As Date
Dim DayOfWeek As Date
Dim i As Integer

mbox = InputBox("Enter Start Date", "Enter Start Date")

If IsDate(mbox) Then
StartDate = CDate(mbox)
Range("d2") = StartDate

    For i = 1 To 14
        Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = StartDate + i
    Next i

Range("d2").CurrentRegion.Offset(, -1).Value = "Eg Tuesday"

Else
MsgBox "Please Enter a Date"
End If

End Sub
```

So the final result would look like

> Tuesday    2019/03/26
>
> Wednesday  2019/03/27

I think I may be facing two issues.

The first being I cannot extract the day of the week from a date that is represented in the style of style 03/26/2019

The second thing is I'm not sure if the manner I am matching Column C (where I want the day of the week present) to Column D where the date style 03/26/2019 is presented is correct.

Comment: You can do this with custom number formats - dddd gives you day of the week so you want  dddd yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: I've been trying that but no luck.  Eg- if I'm not using VBA I can get the result I desire using =TEXT(D2,"dddd") but when I try to use this in the VBA it creates an error 1004. This leads me to think the way I am using the VBA to autofill the cells is incorrect which is my second issue.

Comment: No, it's not a formula, it's a property. Just 
Range("d2").currentregion.numberformat = "dddd yyyy/mm/dd"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using VBA, you need the function `Format`:

```
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim DayOfWeek As Date
Dim i As Integer

mbox = InputBox("Enter Start Date", "Enter Start Date")

If IsDate(mbox) Then
    StartDate = CDate(mbox)
    For i = 0 To 13
        Cells(i + 2, 3) = Format(StartDate + i, "dddd")
        Cells(i + 2, 4).Value = StartDate + i
    Next i
Else
    MsgBox "Please Enter a Date"
End If
```

If you want the routine to display the 14 days *including* the day entered, use this loop instead:

```
For i = 0 To 13
    Cells(i + 2, 3) = Format(StartDate + i, "dddd")
    Cells(i + 2, 4).Value = StartDate + i
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want the weekday and date (as formatted `YYYY/MM/DD`) for each date, which includes:

- The start date
- The next 14 days

So for today (2019-03-26), you'd want the following results:

```
+-----------+------------+
|  Weekday  |    Date    |
+-----------+------------+
| Tuesday   | 2019/03/26 |
| Wednesday | 2019/03/27 |
| Thursday  | 2019/03/28 |
| Friday    | 2019/03/29 |
| Saturday  | 2019/03/30 |
| Sunday    | 2019/03/31 |
| Monday    | 2019/04/01 |
| Tuesday   | 2019/04/02 |
| Wednesday | 2019/04/03 |
| Thursday  | 2019/04/04 |
| Friday    | 2019/04/05 |
| Saturday  | 2019/04/06 |
| Sunday    | 2019/04/07 |
| Monday    | 2019/04/08 |
| Tuesday   | 2019/04/09 |
+-----------+------------+
```

I think your best bet is to create an array that will hold both the formatted date and weekday, and then put that array in the range you want, all at once, at the end:

```
Option Explicit

' declare a constant for the number of dates, to avoid hard-coding it later on.
Private Const NUMBER_OF_DATES As Integer = 15

Public Sub InputDate()
    ' this is your array that will hold the values you need.
    ' note that we'll initialize is later with the ReDim command.
    Dim datesWithWeekdays() As Variant

    ' this will hold the user i
    Dim startDate As Date

    ' this is your initial user input (a String value).
    ' you may want to change the variable name to something
    ' that more closely matches your StartDate (e.g. startDateAsString)
    Dim mbox As String

    ' This is just your counter variable; same as you had before.
    Dim i As Integer

    ' this is a placeholder, to store the date each iteration.
    Dim dt As Date

    ' this is used at the end to put the contents of your array into Excel.
    Dim dest As Excel.Range

    ' here we actually initialize the array.
    ' the number of rows = the number of dates,
    ' and the number of columns is 2.
    ReDim datesWithWeekdays(1 To NUMBER_OF_DATES, 1 To 2)

    mbox = InputBox("Enter Start Date")

    If IsDate(mbox) Then
        startDate = CDate(mbox)

        ' note that we don't do any processing outside the loop.
        ' for the total # of dates (15), calculate the date,
        ' and then assign the appropriate values to the array.
        ' note that I'm using the DateAdd function, which is clearer
        ' than just adding a number to a date.
        ' Also, I'm adding a "'" character in front of the YYYY/MM/DD,
        ' so Excel doesn't try to parse it as a date.
        ' If you want to keep it as a date, and have the format match,
        ' you can instead change the column formatting in Excel.
        For i = 1 To NUMBER_OF_DATES
            dt = DateAdd("d", i - 1, startDate)
            datesWithWeekdays(i, 1) = Format(dt, "dddd")
            datesWithWeekdays(i, 2) = "'" & Format(dt, "YYYY/MM/DD")
        Next i

        ' here, we set up the destination range, and set its value
        ' to the array.
        Set dest = Excel.Range("$D$2")
        Set dest = dest.Resize(rowsize:=NUMBER_OF_DATES, columnsize:=2)
        dest.Value = datesWithWeekdays
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid date"
    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to spend some extra time for no reason i like doing it this way.

```
if range("h6").value = monday then
   range("i6").value = 15
   range("j6").value = 03
   range("k6").value = 2019
else
  if range("h7").value = tuesday then
     range("i7").value = range("i6").value + 1
  else
   (so on through the rest of the days)
end if
```